# No backlight control with HDMI screen?

Tags: hdmi

I have a Eviciv 7 Inch HDMI touchscreen which I really like. One thing that bothers me a lot is that the backlight keeps on when the RPi (3B+) goes to sleep. The screen blanks, but the backlight leds keep burning. There is no hardware switch on the display panel to control the backlight.

I contacted Eviciv support and they said I can control the backlight of the HDMI display with the following command:

echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power

I thought this command only worked on the official DSI RPI touchscreen, but the Eviciv support ensured it works with their HDMI screen too.

I tried this on my Pi, but I got "no such file or directory" when executing the command.
It seems that I even don't have the /sys/class/backlight folder.

So my questions are:

1. Is it correct that "echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power" can control the backlight of an HDMI screen with backlight control?
2. Why is the /sys/class/backlight folder missing on my RPI installation? Does this have to do with the information that is send by the HDMI display to the RPi during installation?
3. Can I somehow get the /sys/class/backlight/... folders installed and working?

I really like this screen but can't accept the backlight to burn 24/7.
Hopefully this can be fixed!

Thanks a lot in advance,

Michiel

Comment: why would a computer be able to control the backight of an HDMI monitor? ... the monitor should go to sleep on its own when the video signal disappears

Comment: this may help ... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52263/how-can-i-put-my-hdmi-display-into-and-out-of-power-save-mode

Comment: @jsotola: you are right... but when the HDMI output is powered off, the display goes to sleep including the touch interface. Which leads to a lockup. I guess the different power modes (as described in the article you referred to) should work, but they don't... So I'll send back the display.